# Building a Pricing Tool with discounts Using C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Okay maybe I am just not using the right search terms but I cannot seem to find anything online anywhere.

Essentially I am trying to build a pricing tool for work. This pricing tool needs to have the ability to take into account discount codes and bundle pricings.

I need to build it in a way that I can have an admin section where I could enter in the discount code and the value of that discount code along with what products that discount code is used for.

I don't expect anyone to tell me how to do this I am a big boy and can read and research it but I am having an issue just getting started. If anyone out there knows of any decent articles online how to do some basic design for this sort of thing please direct me there. From there I can figure the rest out.

Oh by the way I plan on using C# ASP.NET MVC 3

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at some prevalent ecommmerce sites (nopcommerce springs to mind). They all have admin sections and any decent ecommerce site will support coupons and discounts per product. You may even be able to borrow some (open source) code...